# How to remove or hide particular column in a datatable?

Tags: c#

I am using C#. I want to hide or remove the column from DataTable or DataSet  . I attach my partial code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = (DataView)Session["map_hi"];
dt = dv.ToTable();
dt.Columns[0].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: I want to hide or remove the column from DataTable `dt.Columns.Remove("ColumnName")`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this

```
   DataTable t;
   t.Columns.Remove("columnName");
   t.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

Comment: If you have settled up the column as the id (primary key) you won't able to remove it (This scenario happened to me). Otherwise this works.

Comment: Hi @Codinghierarchy, for me also showing me the below error `Cannot remove this column, because it is part of the parent key for relationship DA_StudentList.`

How can i fix it, i don't want to display that perticular column

Answer (score 1):

As Pranay says you can remove columns as `myTable.Columns.Remove("columnName");`

But in my case it throws an exception as "Cannot remove this column, because it is part of the parent key for relationship"

I was able to overcome it as below.

```
  myTable.ParentRelations.Clear();
  myTable.ChildRelations.Clear();
  myTable.Constraints.Clear();
  myTable.Columns.Remove("columnName");
```

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score -3):

Use `Visible` property to hide the specific column:

```
dt.Columns[0].Visible= false;
```

Comment: As far as I know this works only on for _DataGridView_ and not for _DataTable_. So _dt_ could be a bit misleading as variable name in your example.

Comment: @ChristianJunk this was far last year. Besides, this worked for me. I will mention in my answer if i'm not sure about it.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan: I wouldn't post this then. You might have some codes that are changing the value of that.

Comment: @KaeL You shouldn't have. This does not work because Visible is a property of DataGridViewColumn, not DataColumn. The OP is asking about DataTable.

Comment: @xiaomy That's why OP did not mark this as the answer. Thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Answer (score -4):

To hide and show try this:

**For hiding:**

```
dt.Columns[ColumnIndex].Visible = false;
```

or:

```
dt.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

**For showing:**

```
dt.Columns[ColumnIndex].Visible = true;
```

or:

```
dt.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = true;
```

**For removing:**

```
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(ColumnIndex);
```

or:

```
dt.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");
```

Comment: the dt.Column.Visible doesn't contain a definition for Visible